# Generating a maven springboot versioned application

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I use the application.yml to version my app (to look at actuator)

```
info:
    app:
        version: 2.3.0
```

So, is possible to when I run mvn package generate my war with that version I put in application.yml?

tks

Comment: I know it's possible to do it the other way where maven places current version in application.yml (from what the pom version is).  Would that work?